# Rest Assured-java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Tags: java, rest-assured

In restassured am getting the "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect" if I execute the below function tu3 from a different class. If I call the function from parent class, it is successfully executed. Please let me know how to correct this.

```
@Parameters({"Param 1","Param 2"})
  @Test
   public void tu3(@Optional String la, @Optional int StatusCode ) throws 
    IOException


    System.out.println("Test"+la);
    System.out.println(URI);
    given().pathParam("user_ID", la)
    .when().delete("/{user_ID}")
    .then().statusCode(StatusCode);

   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Try to do this  _given().log().uri()_ and check if returned url is correct

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post all code relevant to your question.

Answer (score 0):

here is the problem i guess userid is double quotes

```
.when().delete("/{user_ID}")
```

Correct line should be

```
.when().delete("URL/"+user_ID)
```

Your URL should be URL/1 where 1 is user_id, not URL/{user_id}

You should pass userID to be deleted

In .delete you should provide whole API URL

Comment: When i tried as above that resulted in syntax error . The issue is delete happens if the code is executed from same class, if the class is called from other class it did not work.

Comment: I have edited the line i forgot to add + sign and one more thing can you tell me what is the Value of user id you are trying to delete? because the code you have shared , I cannot see userid value being passed to that function that you are trying to delete.

Comment: I have tried that but it throws illegal argument, as I have mentioned the User_Id(which is a string) if passed {User_Id} in the same class like tu3("jfgg",200) the user gets deleted. If i call the same method from different class then I ma getting connectivity issue.

Comment: Where you are setting your base your  URL?

Comment: in the called class.

Comment: You have to pass that base URL to this method Because if you are calling it from other classes that BASE URL is not accessible to this method. Other solution to this is you can Separate Setup class in which you can add @BeforeMethod annotation and in this you can set Base URL. Extend this class to every class that contains tests.So before running test it will set base URL.